# Dealing with Right Censored Data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-models, censoring

I'm working with a dataset with n of roughly 300,000 and am trying to build a model to predict the time-to-event from multiple explanatory variables, including past times from the same subjects. Roughly 10% of the data is censored (the rest of the data exists) because the event in question has yet to happen. I'm wondering how to deal with this and can think of a few options:

1. Cut off the end of the sample period earlier so as to minimize the amount of censored data. Doing this could cut the censored variables down to maybe 2%-3%. I think for my purposes, maybe these could be considered outliers and thrown out? The potential downside to doing this is that I would prefer to include as recent data as possible as it is more representative of current realities.
2. Use up to the minute data which would include censored observations, but somehow estimate a stand in measurement or otherwise weight them differently.

Any advice or pointers will be much appreciated. Also I'm working with Python just in case anybody wants to reference examples or implementations.

Comment: You shouldn't try to remove or ignore  censored data nor treat it as if the survival duration was the censoring time; you'll bias your estimates. Survival analysis includes a variety of parametric and non-parametric distributional models for survival times that properly treat censoring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time-to-event data with low censoring](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245863/time-to-event-data-with-low-censoring)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you want to predict the duration of some time period from covariates, you would use a proportional hazards model. This  model predicts the instantaneous hazard (probability) of an event ocurring. In R, you would use the survival package and the coxph function. (I don't know about python.)

In general when you are predicting something you think might be normally distributed, conditional on the covariates, but you can only observe values up to a certain (known) point, you would want to use censored regression models (to avoid bias in your parameter estimates, caused by the censoring). You can read about this (also in an R context) here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/censReg/vignettes/censReg.pdf

Comment: Also, if you cut off the end of the sample period early you're throwing away potentially interesting information.

Comment: Not just interesting information -- removing the larger values biases the estimates of duration.